# c# - Optimize SQLite Select statement

Tags: c#, sqlite, select

I am using System.Data.SQLite for my database, and my select statements are very slow. It takes around 3-5 minutes to query around 5000 rows of data. Here is the code I am using:

```
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source={0}", documentsFolder + ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
        //Open a new SQLite Connection
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * From urls";
        //Assign the data from urls to dr
        SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand();
        com.CommandText = "Select * From visits";
        SQLiteDataReader visit = com.ExecuteReader();

        List<int> dbID2 = new List<int>();
        while (visit.Read())
        {
            dbID2.Add(int.Parse(visit[1].ToString()));
        }
        //Read from dr
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string url = dr[1].ToString();
            string title = dr[2].ToString();
            long visitlong = Int64.Parse(dr[5].ToString());
            string browser = "Chrome";
            int dbID = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
            bool exists = dbID2.Any(item => item == dbID);
            int frequency = int.Parse(dr["visit_count"].ToString());

            bool containsBoth = url.Contains("file:///");

            if (exists)
            {
                if (containsBoth == false)
                {
                    var form = Form.ActiveForm as TestURLGUI2.Form1;

                    URLs.Add(new URL(url, title, browser, visited, frequency));
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", title, browser));
                }
            }

        }
        //Close the connection
        conn.Close();
```

And here is another example that takes long:

```
IEnumerable<URL> ExtractUserHistory(string folder, bool display)
{
    // Get User history info
    DataTable historyDT = ExtractFromTable("moz_places", folder);

    // Get visit Time/Data info
    DataTable visitsDT = ExtractFromTable("moz_historyvisits",
                                           folder);



    // Loop each history entry
    foreach (DataRow row in historyDT.Rows)
    {
        // Select entry Date from visits
        var entryDate = (from dates in visitsDT.AsEnumerable()
                         where dates["place_id"].ToString() == row["id"].ToString()
                         select dates).LastOrDefault();
        // If history entry has date
        if (entryDate != null)
        {
            // Obtain URL and Title strings
            string url = row["Url"].ToString();
            string title = row["title"].ToString();
            int frequency = int.Parse(row["visit_count"].ToString());
            string visit_type;

            //Add a URL to list URLs
            URLs.Add(new URL(url, title, browser, visited, frequency));

            // Add entry to list
            //    URLs.Add(u);
            if (title != "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", title, browser));
            }
        }
    }

    return URLs;
}



DataTable ExtractFromTable(string table, string folder)
{
    SQLiteConnection sql_con;
    SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;
    SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();

    // FireFox database file
    string dbPath = folder + "\\places.sqlite";

    // If file exists
    if (File.Exists(dbPath))
    {
        // Data connection
        sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath +
                            ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");

        // Open the Connection
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();

        // Select Query
        string CommandText = "select * from " + table;

        // Populate Data Table
        DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con);
        DB.Fill(DT);

        // Clean up
        sql_con.Close();
    }
    return DT;
}
```

Now, how can I optimize these so that they are faster?

Comment: Have you considered getting the database to do the joins for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to moving more of the data aggregation to SQL as joins, you might also consider getting your `SQLiteDataReader` to provide the data types instead of always parsing the values.

For example, you have the line:

```
long visitlong = Int64.Parse(dr[5].ToString());
```

`dr[5]` is a Sqlite value which you are first converting to a string, then parsing it to a long. These parse operations take time. Why not instead do:

```
long visitlong = dr.GetInt64(5);
```

Or:

```
long visitlong = dr.GetInt64(dr.GetOrdinal("columnName"));
```

Check out [the various methods that SqliteDataReader offers](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader_members.html) and utilize them whenever possible instead of parsing values.

**Edit:**

*Note that this requires the data be stored as the correct type. If everything in the database is stored as a string, some parsing will be unavoidable.*

Comment: Thanks, but I found my problem was that when I run it With Debugging, it is very slow, but when I run it Without Debugging, it finishes within a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've recently run the SQL command "ANALYZE {db|table|index};".

I recently ran into a situation where queries were running fast (<1 sec) in my ER software (Navicat), ie: not debugging, but they were very slow (>1 min) debugging in Visual Studio.  It turned out that because I did my database design in Navicat (SQLite v3.7), the statistics were not the same as those used by System.Data.SQLite in Visual Studio (v3.8).  Running "ANALYZE;" on the entire database file from Visual Studio updated the [sqlite_statX] tables used by v3.8.  Both places were the same speed after that.